# Set Identity In sqlce table to auto increment?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am a beginner programmer (High-School student) and my teacher has given me a task to make a primary key inside a `sqlce` table automatically increment every time I insert a new row into my database ( I don't think he knows how to do it either :)

Here is my Current Code:

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Occupational VALUES(@employedBeforeBool, @nameofEmployer, @Addressemployed,@specificsAtEmployer,@employmentOnDischarge, @yearsExperienceWithEmployer, @desireToReturnToEmployer, @farmingExperienceBool, @tradesorapprentiship, @whattradesorapprentiship, @SoldierID, @Occupational_ID)", con))
    {
        com.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Occupational ON";
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employedBeforeBool", Soldier1.employedBeforeBool);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameofEmployer", Soldier1.nameOfEmployer);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addressemployed", Soldier1.addressOfEmployer);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@specificsAtEmployer", Soldier1.specificsAtEmployer);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employmentOnDischarge", Soldier1.employmentOnDischarge);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearsExperienceWithEmployer", Soldier1.yearsExperienceWithEmployer);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desireToReturnToEmployer", Soldier1.desireToReturnToEmployer);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@farmingExperienceBool", Soldier1.farmingExperienceBool);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tradesorapprentiship", Soldier1.tradeOrApprenticeship);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whattradesorapprentiship", Soldier1.whattradesorapprentiship);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SoldierID", SoldierID);
        //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupational_ID", counter);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

My program doesn't crash when I run it and it looks like it is inserting but nothing is showing up inside the table.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code overwrites the `INSERT INTO` query with the `SET IDENTITY` text. There is only 1 CommandText property.

And making a column auto-increment is done when you create the table, you shouldn't have to do anything during an insert.

If you used the designer to create the table, go back and set the `IDENTITY` property to true for the Key column.

Comment: I understand that it overwrites the query but if i  Take out the @Occupational_ID from the insert statement then i get the following error "The number of columns in the query and the table must match. [ Number of columns in query = 11, Number of columns in table = 12 ]" (The Identity colomun is already set to true for Occupational_ID when i created the table)

Comment: Simply remove the Occupational_ID from both parts of the Insert statement. When it's set up right you don't have to Insert it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Henk said, you can't have two different CommandTexts for a given SQLCECommand. 
As long as you identified the field/column as an Identity when you built the table then you need to make sure that you take out any reference to your identity column (yours is @Occupational_ID) inside the command itself.

However, there are two very important facts that weren't stated previously:

1. You need two separate SQLCECommands (one for turning the Identity on and a second for the actual Insert). Add the following inside your 'using' statement:

   SqlCeCommand identChangeCommand = new SqlCeCommand(con);
   identChangeCommand.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Occupational ON";
2. You need to add the starting value of your identity column inside the Insert. Because you are using an integer as the data type you can choose any integer value to start with. Every Insert after that will add one to the previous value Inserted:

   using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Occupational VALUES(1000, @employedBeforeBool, ...

PS make sure that you ExecuteNonQuery() both of the commands.
Hope that helps!